# MVVM Update binding issue

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have user control to which I bind a viewmodel, this implements the INotifyPropertyChanged,  thru the datacontext, this has a property that is a IList that I bind to the itemsdatasource of a grid, then on the code, in another class I add some values to the list, but the UI doesn't reflect this change although in debug I can see that the datagrid has this items added but they don't appear in the UI, can anybody help me, I can't see what is the problem.

Answer (score 5):

[`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) is your friend. It implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), saving you the trouble.